# Export and import modules of an installation

Tags: importing-exporting

In almost every drupal installation I set up, I use a package of modules. So my question is simple. Is there any way or module or something like that that will do this in an easy way?

To be more specific I am searching for a tool or something like that that will export a list of selected modules from one drupal installation. Then after a fresh installation, I would import this list and the modules would be automatically installed.

Is there any tool/module that can achieve what I described?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drush Make can easily create a makefile of all the modules installed on a site, and `drush make [make-file]` can instantly download those modules to an empty drupal project folder.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing two kinds of workflows.

One way is to use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) - where you package functionality into modules. In your case, you would create a Feature, select modules as dependencies as well as any configuration you want to carry forward. When the feature is enabled, all those modules are enabled.

Another way is defining dependencies with Composer (8.x) and combine that using Features and build tasks to automate this further, where nuking and reinstalling Drupal returns to the same state, kind of like an install profile in a sense.